# How to get these timestamps, which come after in the html, to float right on the same line

Tags: css

I have some markup, which I can't change, that looks like this:

```
<div class="message">
  <p class="messageText">Long long long long long long long long long message that wraps</p>
  <span class="timestamp">6:30:07 PM</span>
</div>
<div class="message">
   ...
```

How can I style this with CSS to look something like this?:

```
Long long long long long long                            6:30:07 PM
long long long message that wraps
Next message                                             6:31:58 PM
```

I want the timestamps to go over on the right, directly to the right of the message they correspond to.

If the timestamps appeared *before* the messages in the markup, I could just float them right and everything would work fine. How do I do it in my case, given that they appear *after* the messages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming these timestamps always consist of the same amount of characters, and therefor will all have (roughly) the same width, positioning them absolutely would be an easy solution:

```
.message { position:relative; padding-right:5em; }
.timestamp { position:absolute; top:0; right:0; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pao17yeb/

The `padding-right` “reserves” space that the message text can’t flow into, so that it’ll wrap before.

Should that not be possible, using flexbox to reverse the display order of the items might be an alternative way to go about this.